# Is Gayatri and Yogic practice compatible with Pure Bhakti practice or not

Tags: vishnu, bhakti, gayatri-mantra, chakras, kundalini

This is my doubt, and now again...

Is Gayatri and Yogic practice compatible with Pure Bhakti practice or not?!

**Explanation**:

I have practiced many things and sādhanas, I'm not the first day, BUT...
I have always practiced and loved Mantra yoga & Bhakti Yoga....The last years mainly concentrating on Šrīman Nārāyana bhakti and mantra path...

AND - I always have been very much Anti-Yoga and Anti-Chakra, Anti-Kundalini person... From my inner experience - most Kundalini things are sexual energy -related and Tantric things - and I would like to be as far as possible from that part of popular practice... Even more as a celibate person - and I can see around so many so called "pseudo-yogis" with aroused sexual energy and not able to observe strict celibacy....Also - I am not doing any conscious Pranayamas - when I was young - I did tried some pranayama, my brain went out of usual, and since then I am very adverse to any breath regulations.... However - I believe the breath is controlled by Mantra practice themselves...

With above told - I don't feel any tantric negative influence while doing Nārāyana japa.... just a Pure Bhakti....

Also to mention - there are some pandits - who are trying to scare off people, telling - you cannot do this or that mantra without diksha, etc.... - I believe - if I surrender to God - there can never be any negative influence, just Divine Will; but if I do some Kundalini - there indeed can be negative influence, etc....

Now - I hear very often - it is considered very beneficial to do Gayatrī (Devī Gāyatrī) mantra...

But again - I am very concerned to do Gāyatri japa practice, because the explanation of Gāyatrī - always come from Yogic persons - they tell you - Gāyatri arouses Kundalinī, that chakra, that chakra, blah, blah, blah... I don't want to arouse any of my chakras, for God's sake... I only wish to pray God and surrender to God's Will... I don't care about their chakra/ kundalini staff...

So - I cannot decide to do Gayatri practice or not... (I do a little bit anyways, a few times every prayer time, but that is not a serious dedcated practice)

Comment: Gayatri practice should not be done without upanayana samskara. Also about Tantric negative influence, Tantra and Kundalini ain't about sexual things. Kindly read more. Tantra is vast.

Comment: You have a whole lot of wrong ideas. Moreover, Gayatri mantra sadhana has nothing to do with Yoga.

Comment: Gayatri mantra can be chanted by everyone. Even women. In olden days also women of great caliber like Gargi.... have done it. Kundalini has been misunderstood by many. You need not bother about all chakras and Kundalini. Just do your Japa. Have Faith in God. Bhakthi and Gayatri and Yoga were never incompatible. People used them for selfish purposes that does not mean they arent good. Infact I do Gayatri to develope devotion . It is very effective.

Comment: Friends, I am not based in "Ideas" - I am based in Practice; and if I say - my 30 years daily practice is this, this is very much true what I am telling you;

Comment: So- Yes, Kundalini, Tantra, Yoga - they ARE about Sexual things, because I know those things from my experience, I can feel and see as energy is flowing through body, and I am telling this - so this is true, and you should listen what I am telling, instead of reading some other fake books;

Comment: I am interested in Experiences of qualified practitioners, not in some general theories or ideas; Sexual = is all Prāņa related, as opposed to Conscious related;

Comment: Please don't mention SEX many times in your comments.   It indicates that unknowingly you are being drawn towards that aspect.   Remember that life will not follow our own way of thinking.  If you are destined for sexual bliss,  you will be drawn towards it however hard you may try.  You are inclined to do  NARAYANA mantra Japa.  So stick to it.  That recitation will guide you further.   However,  keep your mind open to the wish of the Almighty God.@user1981528

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, pure bhakti is completely internal. So you can be doing yogic assanas and be in the perfect love of God within your heart. I think this what perfected yogis do.

The more you advance spiritually, the more you understand things and go deeper in your self, you see how spiritual practices are compatible and work together. One man could be a Buddhist yogi. Another could be an enlightened jhani. There are many exotic combinations of spiritual life that make up a complete spiritual being.

In the beginning, they don't seem to work together and one may feel hampered or lost/confused by different spiritual practices. So it is recommended to follow one discipline to the end or as much as you can, before entering another.

Comment: It's not about "seeming"; it's a question about inner energies how flow and work, and I expect everybody feels and realises this; the other side of the question - Yoga is primarily a Business, and - again - I am happy to renounce that business; if their goal were to save all sentient beings - they would do it for free; and the 3rd part - the Mind/Consciousness - is always First, everything comes from the consciousness and God; and if one intends to make Consciousness Perfect - they do train their consciousness; otherwise they do train body, breath, etc....

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question although there is no need of being afraid of chakras. The classical requirements for practicing Bhakti Yoga are given by Prahlada’s nine points of devotion

> Hearing about Vishnu, singing about Him, remembering Him, serving Him,
>   saluting Him, being His servant, being His comrade, and surrendering
>   oneself and everything that is one’s own to Him – these are the nine
>   aspects of Bhakti or God-love. If man could be trained to practice
>   devotion characterised by these nine features that indeed would be the
>   highest education he could have.

***Srimad Bhagavata Purana VII.5.23-24***

As you can see there is no talk of Gayatri and Yogic practice. So why do some people practice raising Kundalini while others do not? There is a good explanation given by Sir John Woodroffe.

> If you want to rouse Kundalini Sakti to enjoy the bliss of union of
>   Siva and Sakti through Her, which your capacities do not otherwise
>   allow you to have or if you wish to gain the accompanying powers
>   (Siddhi), it is obvious that this end can only be achieved by the Yoga
>   here described. But if liberation is sought and **the Yogi has the
>   capacity to attain it without Kundalini, then such Yoga is not
>   necessary,** for liberation may be obtained by pure Jnana Yoga through
>   detachment, the exercise, and then the stilling of the mind without
>   any reference to the central bodily power at all. Indeed perfect
>   liberation (Nirvikalpa Samadhi) can only be obtained in this way by
>   Raja-Yoga of which Kundalini-Yoga is a preliminiary method. **Samadhi
>   may also be attained on the path of devotion (Bhakti), as on that of
>   knowledge. Indeed, the highest devotion (Para-Bhakti) is not different
>   from knowledge. Both are realization.**

***The Serpent Power the secrets of tantric and shaktic yoga, chapter 7, by Arthur Avalon (Sir John Woodroffe)***

**Bhakti Yoga is for those people who are able to love God intensely. They do not need any Yogic practice.** What should a spiritual aspirant do if he finds that he is unable to love God intensely?. Such a person has a choice of Jnana Yoga or raising the Kundalini Shakti. If he is able to do Jnana Yoga then he does not need to raise Kundalini either. What does he do if he finds Jnana Yoga beyond his capacity? Then he has to fall back on raising his Kundalini shakti. Kundalini Herself, when roused by the Yogi, achieves for him this illumination.